# How to Install Compiz Extra Animations Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, compiz, 12.10, animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Compiz extra animations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203935/how-do-i-install-compiz-extra-animations)

I tried to install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra to get the burn effect and more animations for Compiz, but the terminal told me it was unable to locate that package. How do you install the extra Compiz animations in Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal? Thanks in advance!