# How do I install Compiz extra animations?

Tags: compiz

I have tried the `sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra` in the terminal window but it said that it can't find it, so if anyone of you know a way to get the extra animations I would be thankful for an answer!

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

The package contents have been moved to `compiz-plugins` and the dummy package was removed in 12.10.

This was the state in 12.04:

```
$ aptitude show compiz-fusion-plugins-extra 
Package: compiz-fusion-plugins-extra     
[...]
Depends: compiz-plugins-extra
Description: transitional dummy package.

 This package ensures a clean upgrade path, and can be safely removed after the
 upgrade.
Homepage: http://www.compiz.org/

$ aptitude show compiz-plugins-extra 
Package: compiz-plugins-extra            
[...]
Description: Collection of extra plugins from OpenCompositing for Compiz
 The OpenCompositing Project brings 3D desktop visual effects that improve
 usability of the X Window System and provide increased productivity. 

 This package contains extra plugins and themes contributed by the community
 giving a rich desktop experience.
Homepage: http://www.compiz.org/
```

Note that `compiz-plugins-extra` now is a dummy package in 12.10, too.

Comment: There sadly are no extra animantions in the compiz-plugins package. So this answer doesn't help.

Comment: Why is that??? Aren't they build yet?